# Rails on Webfaction (Passenger and Nginx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, webfaction

This is my first time deploying a Rails app to a production server, I have already done almost everything. I'm stuck with the process to make the app run in production mode, I already typed

```
 $ export RAILS_ENV=production
```

and

```
 $ echo $RAILS_ENV
```

and the terminal throws that I am in the **production** mode, but when I go to a url in my app not yet defined by me, the server **is still debugging the templates**, I just want the server throws the default 404 page.

Be patient to me I'm new in this. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `rails_env` setting in nginx/conf/nginx.conf, as follows:

```
server {
    listen             <port_number>;
    passenger_enabled  on;
    root               /home/<username>/webapps/<app_name>/<app>/public;
    server_name        localhost;
    rails_env          production;
}
```

If you do this and are greeted with a "502 Bad Gateway" error for your efforts, the issue may be that you don't have the `SECRET_KEY_BASE` environment variable set. You can generate a suitable value with `rake secret`, and then add `export SECRET_KEY_BASE="<secret>"` wherever you're setting other environment variables.

Webfaction's Rails deployment documentation has improved substantially, but this is one of a number of non-intuitive steps it still skips over.